# Letter conversion program for Ada

Tags: ada

I made a letter conversion program in Ada that will take any lowercase letter and change it to uppercase and vice versa. The entire thing works until you get to my argument_count = 3 portion. Its supposed to output text to another file, and its just not working at all. My exception error `when others=> error` keeps popping up.

It's supposed to go something like this when you input it into terminal or command-line:

```
./case_converter u plain.text output
```

---

```
With Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Command_Line, Ada.Characters.Handling;
Use Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Command_Line, Ada.Characters.Handling;

Procedure case_conversion is

    Argument_Error : Exception; --the excpetion raise for bad command-line arguments.
    Input, Output  : File_Type;-- input and output files, if specified.
    File           : File_Type; 
    Eol           : Boolean;
    Char           : Character;

Function To_Upper (upper : Character) Return Character is  

Begin

    Case upper is 

        When 'a' =>
            Return 'A';
        When 'b' =>
            Return 'B';
        When 'c' =>
            Return 'C';
        When 'd' =>
            Return 'D';
        When 'e' =>
            Return 'E';
        When 'f' =>
            Return 'F';
        When 'g' =>
            Return 'G';
        When 'h' =>
            Return 'H';
        When 'i' => 
            Return 'I';
        When 'j' =>
            Return 'J';
        When 'k' =>
            Return 'K';
        When 'l' =>
            Return 'l';
        When 'm' =>
            Return 'M';
        When 'n' =>
            Return 'N';
        When 'o' =>
            Return 'O';
        When 'p' =>
            Return 'P';
        When 'q' =>
            Return 'Q';
        When 'r' =>
            Return 'R';
        When 's' =>
            Return 'S';
        When 't' =>
            Return 'T';
        When 'u' =>
            Return 'U';
        When 'v' =>
            Return 'V';
        When 'w' =>
            Return 'W';
        When 'x' =>
            Return 'X';
        When 'y' =>
            Return 'Y';
        When 'z' =>
            Return 'Z';
        When Others =>
            Return char; -- This will let me know if there is a bug in the code, and to just return char.
    end case;
end To_Upper;


Function To_Lower (lower : Character) Return character is              

Begin

    Case lower is

        When 'A' =>
            Return 'a';
        When 'B' =>
            Return 'b';
        When 'C' =>
            Return 'c';
        When 'D' =>
            Return 'd';
        When 'E' =>
            Return 'e';
        When 'F' =>
            Return 'f';
        When 'G' =>
            Return 'g';
        When 'H' =>
            Return 'h';
        When 'I' =>
            Return 'i';
        When 'J' =>
            Return 'j';
        When 'K' =>
            Return 'k';
        When 'L' =>
            Return 'l';
        When 'M' =>
            Return 'm';
        When 'N' =>
            Return 'n';
        When 'O' =>
            Return 'o';
        When 'P' =>
            Return 'p';
        When 'Q' =>
            Return 'q';
        When 'R' =>
            Return 'r';
        When 'S' =>
            Return 's';
        When 'T' =>
            Return 't';
        When 'U' =>
            Return 'u';
        When 'V' =>
            Return 'v';
        When 'W' =>
            Return 'w';
        When 'X' =>
            Return 'x';
        When 'Y' =>
            Return 'y';
        When 'Z' =>
            Return 'z';
        When Others =>
            Return char; 

    end case;
End To_Lower;


begin

        If argument_count < 1 then
            Raise Argument_Error;
        end if;

           IF Argument_Count > 1 THEN 
        null;     
   END IF; 

   IF Argument_Count > 2 THEN 
        null; 
   END IF;   

      If argument_Count = 1 then
            loop          
                look_Ahead (Char, Eol);       
                    if Argument (1) = "U" or Argument (1) = "u" then
                           Get (char);
                           Char := (To_Upper(char));
                          Put (char);
                        elsif
                               Argument (1) = "L" or Argument (1) = "l" then
                            Get (char);
                            Char := (To_Lower(char));
                            Put (char);
                       end if;  
                   end loop;
            end if;

-----------------------------------------------------------                   

        If Argument_Count = 2 then            
           Open (file, In_File, Argument (2));
        end if;

        While Not End_of_File (file) loop
               Look_Ahead (File, Char, EoL);

                If Argument (1) = "U" or Argument (1) = "u" then
                   Get (file, char);
                   Char := (To_Upper(char));
                   Put (char);
                elsif
                       Argument (1) = "L" or Argument (1) = "l" then
                    Get (file, char);
                    Char := (To_Lower(char));
                    Put (char);
               end if;     


    If EoL then
               New_Line;
        end if; 
end loop;

------------------------------------------------------------    
          If Argument_Count = 3 then
            Open (file, In_File, Argument (2));
            Create (Output, Out_file, Argument(3));



              While Not End_of_File (file) loop 
             -- Look_Ahead (file, Char, EoL);
                              If EoL then
                             New_Line(output);
                         end if;   
                 If Argument (1) = "U" or Argument (1) = "u" then


                           Get (file, char);
                           Char := (To_Upper(char));
                           Put (output, char);

                       elsif Argument (1) = "L" or Argument (1) = "l" then                           
                               ---------
                                  If Eol then
                                      new_line (output);
                                  end if;
                                Get (file, char);
                                Char := (To_Lower(char));
                                Put (output, char);

                      end if;             
    end loop;
end if;


   IF Is_Open(input) THEN 
      Close(Input); 
   END IF; 

   IF Is_Open(Output) THEN 
      Close(Output); 
   END IF;



EXCEPTION
   WHEN Name_Error =>
      Put_Line("The file " & Argument(2) & " cannot be used for input");
   WHEN OTHERS =>
      Put_Line("Usage: case_converter U|L [infile [outfile]]");

end case_conversion;
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not the `Ada.Characters.Handling.To_Upper` (and `To_Lower`) Function?

If you really need to check that the character is alphabetic use `Is_Letter`.

Answer (score 3):

It's often a bad idea to catch exceptions with a `when others`, unless you're sure what exceptions might be raised (and even very experienced developers can get this wrong).

In your case, you should comment out the 'when others' lines; when you run your program and the exception occurs, it will be reported (usually with the line number where it happened, though not - on my machine - in this case). It helps to get a stack trace: this is harder on Mac OS X than on other machines, I wrote about it [here](http://forward-in-code.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/debugging-and-stack-traces-on-mac-os-x.html).

I ran

```
$ ./case_conversion u case_conversion.adb t  

Execution terminated by unhandled exception
Exception name: ADA.IO_EXCEPTIONS.STATUS_ERROR
Message: file not open
Call stack traceback locations:
0x1000103bc 0x10000c9eb 0x100001e9a 0x100001a19
```

and decoded the stack trace with

```
$ atos -o case_conversion 0x1000103bc 0x10000c9eb 0x100001e9a 0x100001a19
system__file_io__check_read_status (in case_conversion) (s-fileio.adb:207)
ada__text_io__end_of_file (in case_conversion) (a-textio.adb:304)
_ada_case_conversion (in case_conversion) (case_conversion.adb:177)
main (in case_conversion) (b~case_conversion.adb:265)
```

and looked at `case_conversion.adb:177`:

```
173    if Argument_Count = 2 then
174       Open (File, In_File, Argument (2));
175    end if;
176
177    while not End_Of_File (File) loop
```

So, what happens if `Argument_Count` is 3?

If you're not running on Mac OS X, instead of [atos](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/atos/) try [addr2line](http://linux.die.net/man/1/addr2line).

Comment: Alternatively, leave the existing "when others" but add the line " raise;" to re-raise the exception (another way to see what the real problem is). As for the real problem : Simon's analysis is spot on. (on some systems, the command you need is "addr2line" not "atos" to get the error location.)

Comment: Yes, Brian, but OP has been asking about getting GNAT to run on Mac.

Comment: the OP's Mac-specific situation may not be obvious to other readers.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking the tick in the left margin (if not, of course, don't).

Answer (score -1):

Shark has it right BTW. Its silly not to use the built-in routine for this.

However, if you were to want to write it yourself for some weird reason, the fact that the letters are contiguous and in the same sequence for upper and lower makes the way you are going about it even sillier. Notice that every entry in those big honking case statements of yours are the same distrance from each other. To make each case entry, you could just copy the previous one and increase the value of both sides by one. This is the exact kind of repeated mechanical activity we invented computers to help us with, isn't it? :-)

The traditional way to covert between the two is to just add the difference between the two sets of characters in the collating sequence (most folks pick the letter 'A'). For example:

```
Upper_To_Lower_Difference : constant := character'pos('a') - character'pos('A');

function To_Upper (Lower : character) return character is
begin
    if Lower in 'a'..'z' then
        return character'val(character'pos(Lower) + Upper_To_Lower_Difference);
    end if;
    return Lower;
end To_Upper;
```

Comment: I was able to get it to work. I just added my argument 1 and 2 statements with my 3rd and presto. I also know that there are built in types, but this is the way I was told to program it.